# Extracting JSON value from key

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON object like so, and I need to extract the `name` value of any object, using the `id`. I have tried many different iterations of this but I can't seem to get anything to work. Any general pointers would be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
{
  "weeks":[
    {
      "1":[
        {
          "name":"Stackoverflow Question",
          "description":"Have you ever asked a question on StackoverFlow?",
          "date":"11/25/2019",
          "id":"whewhewhkahfasdjkhgjks"
        },
        {
          "name":"I Can't Believe It's Not Butter!",
          "description":"Can you believe it? I sure can't.",
          "date":"11/25/2019",
          "id":"agfasdgasdgasdgawe"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "2":[
        {
          "name":"Hello World",
          "description":"A hello world.",
          "date":"12/02/2019",
          "id":"aewgasdgewa"
        },
        {
          "name":"Testing 123",
          "description":"Sometimes people don't say it be like it is but it do.",
          "date":"12/04/2019",
          "id":"asdgasdgasdgasd"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: Have you actually converted this JSON object into a Python dictionary? A look at your code would be quite helpful.

Comment: @KlausD. Yeah, I know that's etiquette and I usually do that, problem is I've just tried various fragmented solutions then deleted them. Apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope you need to find the name based on id, then try out the code below,

```
def get_name(data, id):
    for week in data['weeks']:
        for i in week:
            for j in week[i]:
                if j['id'] == id:
                    return j['name']
    return None

get_name(data, 'asdgasdgasdgasd')
```

output

```
'Testing 123'
```

Comment: Will try this now.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for

```
for week in a["weeks"]:
    for k, v in week.values():
        print(v['name'])
```

considering the variable a your dict.

Answer (score 0):

Is the structure fixed, or can the depth of the JSON differ from the example?

This one would work as well if there are more or lesser hierarchies.
It basically searches in each dictionary inside a JSON-like structure for the field_name and returns the value of the argument output_name.

Maybe it helps you when your data structure changes :)

```
data = {
  "weeks":[
    {
      "1":[
        {
          "name":"Stackoverflow Question",
          "description":"Have you ever asked a question on StackoverFlow?",
          "date":"11/25/2019",
          "id":"whewhewhkahfasdjkhgjks"
        },
        {
          "name":"I Can't Believe It's Not Butter!",
          "description":"Can you believe it? I sure can't.",
          "date":"11/25/2019",
          "id":"agfasdgasdgasdgawe"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "2":[
        {
          "name":"Hello World",
          "description":"A hello world.",
          "date":"12/02/2019",
          "id":"aewgasdgewa"
        },
        {
          "name":"Testing 123",
          "description":"Sometimes people don't say it be like it is but it do.",
          "date":"12/04/2019",
          "id":"asdgasdgasdgasd"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

def extract_name(data, field_name: str, matching_value: str, output_name: str):
    """

    :param data: json-like datastructure in which you want to search
    :param field_name: the field name with which you want to match
    :param matching_value: the value you want to match
    :param output_name: the name of the value which you want to get
    :return:
    """
    if isinstance(data, list):
        for item in data:
            res = _inner_extract_name(item, field_name, matching_value, output_name)
            if res is not None:
                return res
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        for item in data.values():
            res = _inner_extract_name(item, field_name, matching_value, output_name)
            if res is not None:
                return res


def _inner_extract_name(item, field_name, matching_value, output_name):
    if isinstance(item, dict):
        res = extract_name(item, field_name, matching_value, output_name)
        if field_name in item:
            if item[field_name] == matching_value:
                if output_name in item:
                    return item[output_name]
    else:
        res = extract_name(item, field_name, matching_value, output_name)
    return res


if __name__ == "__main__":
    name = extract_name(data, "id", "aewgasdgewa", "name")
    print(name)
``
```